# Connection string in the web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, connection-string

I am creating a Web API and trying to have the connection string created in the web.config file as

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ProConnection" connectionString="Data Source=J;User ID=T;Password=C;pooling=true;min pool size=5;Max Pool Size=60" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
  <connectionStrings>
```

So I can encrypt the Connection string using aspnet_regiis.exe. So in the controller I am using the below code where dbconn holds the connection details

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
    { 
     string dbconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProConnection"].ConnectionString;
        {
            var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
            var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
            DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
            var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN (" + srtcon + ")";
            OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(selectResults);
            string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
            string contentDisposition = "inline; filename=abc.json";
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result,     MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =  ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition); 
            return response;
       }
   }
```

But I am getting error in the 
[image]

Comment: your ora conn string don't seem correct --> www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: this is a weird syntax  `string dbconn = ConfigurationManager...ConnectionString;
        {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use your connection string directly in the `OracleCommand` rather than creating an `OracleConnection` with it and passing that to your `OracleCommand` instead:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
{ 
    var connectionStringSection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProConnection"];
    string connectionString = connectionStringSection.ConnectionString;
    using (OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
        var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
        DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
        var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN (" + srtcon + ")";
        using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbConn))
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand))
            {
                DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(selectResults);
                string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
                string contentDisposition = "inline; filename=abc.json";
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result,         MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =  ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition); 
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that you should be using `using` statements around your `OracleConnection/Command/DataAdapters` or you risk memory leaks.

Comment: this is the correct way of doing it :) and +1 for emphasizing `using` because any transactions will rollback if it fails

Comment: @Sherlock thanks for the edit. Pesky mobile screws up the formatting :(

Comment: @Daen Ward The error went away with the 'using' but I am getting the error when I am running the application as  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} in the connectionString

Comment: @trx then there's something wrong with your configuration file; it's unable to resolve `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProConnection"]`. Time to break out a debugger.

Comment: Is there any issue with web.config file

Comment: @trx possibly; I updated the post - if `connectionStringSection` is null then there's probably something wrong with your configuration file.

Comment: @trx the difference between your code and this answer is you are not instantiating an instance of `OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection(connectionString)` instead you just passed the string `dbConn` to the `OracleCommand` constructor. But this one expects this params `(string, DBConnection)`. You passed it this way `(string, string)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this a string:

```
var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN (" + srtcon + ")";
            OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
```

to:

```
String strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN (" + srtcon + ")";
            OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
```

Also try this:

```
dbconn.Open();
 OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand ();
 selectCommand = dbconn.CreateCommand();
 selectCommand = new OracleCommand (strQuery, dbconn);
```